# I am trying to create sprites but it isn't working

Tags: css, wordpress, css-sprites

I have a css file with

```
#carouselapis1 {
    background: url('www.apis-iq.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/carousel-apis-software.png') 0 0;
    width: 177px;
    height: 155px;
}
.carouselapis2 {
        background: url('www.apis-iq.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/carousel-apis-software.png') no-repeat -182 0;
        width: 154px;
        height:155px;
}
```

and so on. 
and the code i am pasting in to the text of my wordpress page is:

```
<img class="carouselapis1" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/carousel-forground-no-image.png" alt="carousel-apis-software-saves-time-and-money" width="85" height="155" />
```

whereby the src image is a small blank image. and in the css file the image i want to appear. For some reason though, the image from my css file is not appearing and instead no image shows. 
can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong pls?

Comment: add `http://` to the image url: `http://www.apis-iq.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/carousel-apis-software.png`. And check the image path, it seems this image doesn't exists.

Comment: hi, for some reados the other part i posted didnt post. This is the part i paste in my wordpress text page:<img class="carouselapis1" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/carousel-forground-no-image.png" alt="carousel-apis-software-saves-time-and-money" width="85" height="155" />

Comment: i tried putting https:// but that hasn't changed anything. also i paste this path into mozilla and the image appears.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add http:// to the image url:

```css
.test {
  width: 177px;
  height: 155px;
  background-image: url('https://www.apis-iq.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/carousel-apis-software.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Do i have to wrap it in a div? And why is it cutting off a part of the image? The part top left where the three triangles are?

Comment: The image looks ok for me. What you mean with "Do i have to wrap it in a div?"

Comment: why can't i simply add the class to the img itself? i.e. <img class="carouselapis1" src...

Comment: It makes no sense to add a background image to an image element. If you want to use a sprite, you should use an background image, because you need to change the background position.